# Simple for-loop around for-loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a for-loop to calculate the period time `T`. 
This works when I have one vector for I, but now I have two more vectors.

My idea is to put all I's, I1, I2 and I3 in a matrix `I` and then create a `for` loop around the initial `for` loop beneath here. But I can't seem to get it to work. Is it possible or should I go for another approach?

Please let me know if I should clarify anything.

```
for n = 1:length(I) - 1;
    if I(n)*I(n+1) >= 0 
        n = n+1;
    else
        g = (I(n+1)-I(n))/(tt(n+1)-tt(n));
        T = 2*(tt(n)-(I(n)/g)); 
        disp(' Period [Seconds]:')
        disp(T);
        break
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I do not understand your question, can you provide a sample input and the desired output?

Comment: The code you posted calculates the first time when I turns to zero (presumably, it's alternating current or something like that). If you have three currents I1, I2, I3, they might turn to zero at different times. In order to do something sensible with them in Matlab, you first have to clarify the situation: is the period expected to be the same? What about the phases? What is it that you want to achieve? "now I have two more vectors" is not a clear problem statement.

Comment: So I1, 12 and I3 are, lets say 1x3000 vector. I now want to add them to a matrix I which is 3x3000. And make a for-loop around  the original script to calculate all I's and save T1, T2 and T3 in a vector. I1, I2 and I3 are all different currents, or more precisely vectors with values of the current indicated. Hope this clears it up :)

Comment: Then use `I(k,n)` and `T(k)` instead of `I(n)` and `T`, where k=1,2,3 is the outer for-loop.

Comment: ThP: Works a bit, I get a loooong vector with the value of T, but just for one I, not all three.

Comment: Thanks ThP! Had to do some minor changes but now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TS = [];
Tsvang = [];

for k = 1:3

for n = 1:length(I(k,:)) - 1;
if I(k,n)*I(k,n+1) >= 0 
n = n+1;
else
g = (I(k,n+1)-I(k,n))/(tt(n+1)-tt(n));
Tsvang(k) = 2*(tt(n)-(I(k,n)/g)); 
break
end;
TS = [TS Tsvang];
end;
end;
disp(' Period [Seconds]:')
disp(Tsvang)
```